# Counting problem: ways to empty glasses

Tags: combinatorics

Sorry for my bad english And also my bad math literature in asking my first question.

Assume we have 15 glass full of water.

I need to count the number of possible ways which I can empty 5 glass in a way that no 2 empty glass remain in sequence.

Comment: Are the glasses identical except for being full or empty?

Comment: Yes, they are. I found 11!/5! For answer. Is it correct ?

Comment: Just to clarify the question.  You have 15 full glasses which full, and you want to know how many ways you can empty 5 glasses so no two neighbouring glasses are empty.  Are these glasses arranged in a straight line such that the first and last glasses have only one neighbour each while all others have two neighbours or in a circle so all glasses have two neighbours?

Comment: Nice ! My question was exactly what you explain and glasses were in on straight line. But I'm eagle to know answer for both case !

Comment: Looking at it in reverse, we can first place $5$ empty glasses in a row.  Now we must have $4$ full glasses in between them, to fulfil the constraint.  We are now free to distribute remaining $6$ glasses in any of $6$ locations (in between or outside) the empty glasses.  So this is equivalent to putting $6$ identical balls in $6$ different boxes, where some boxes can even be empty...

Comment: Is this correct: The ways we could select 5 glass which no 2 one be in sequence, is similar to selecting 10 glasses between 15 empty glass to make them full of water. So, We could first put 10 full glasses. Then there are 11 possible places for 5 empty glasses.( no two empty glass should share one of this 11 places) . Therefor: (11x10x9x8x7)/5! = C(11,5)

Comment: Yes - that seems good too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at it in reverse, we can first place $5$ empty glasses in a row. Now we must have $4$ full glasses in between them, to fulfil the constraint. We are now free to distribute remaining $6$ glasses in any of $6$ locations (in between or outside) the empty glasses.

So this is equivalent to putting $6$ identical balls in $6$ different boxes, where some boxes can even be empty...  Which is $C(6+6-1, 6) = C(11, 6)$.

Comment: I think C(11,5) is correct. Isn't it ?

Comment: $C(11, 5) = C(11, 6)$

Comment: You are definitely right. Sorry.

Comment: It just depends on whether you are arranging empty glasses or full glasses in the end. The result is the same.

Comment: I'm studing this topic and got good inspirations from your solution. Can you please add some extra information to your answer like, How will answer change if glasses were in different color? Although I think answer should remain same Because sequence of emptying is not important in question, but your answer seems will change.

Comment: And also what if glasses were identical, but as Warren Hill said, they were in circle for example. I'm really looking forward to know answer for these cases also to learn to make different between these case.

Comment: Unfortunately these new cases seem cumbersome.  In case of different colours, one could look at $f(n, m)$ to represent ways of emptying $m$ glasses from among $n$.  Then one can get a recursion going like $f(n+1, m) = n(f(n, m) + f(n, m-1))$ which allows calculation of $f(15, 5)$ starting from smaller cases.  Small cases are like $f(n, m) = 0$ if $n \le 2m-2, f(n, 1)= n!, f(2m-1, m) = (2m-1)!$ etc. I suggest you should work out a few simpler examples first. Also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelvefold_way#Intuitive_meaning_of_the_rows_and_columns has several good cases.

Answer (score 0):

If the glasses are in a line, say we draw a full glass as a star $*$, and an empty glass as a vertical bar $|$. Then a possible way to empty five glasses is drawn as a line of five stars and ten bars, where the bars are not next to each other. One such way could be drawn as

$|**|**|**|**|**$

This is similar to the problem discussed as Theorem One in [Stars and bars notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29), except the bars can be placed on the ends as well. We can solve the problem by considering four cases:

1. There is no bar on either the left end or the right end. This is then the same as Theorem One in the link, with $k=10$ and $n=6$, so there are $\binom{9}{5}$ of these.
2. There is a bar on the left end. Then ignore this bar, and the rest of the line follows Theorem One with $k=10$ and $n=5$, so there are $\binom{9}{4}$ of these.
3. There is a bar on the right end. Same as case 2, $\binom{9}{4}$ of these.
4. There is a bar on both ends. Ignore them both, and now $n=4$, so $\binom{9}{3}$ of these.

The total number of arrangements is then $\binom{9}{5} + 2\binom{9}{4} + \binom{9}{3} = \binom{10}{5} + \binom{10}{4} = \binom{11}{5}.$